# How do I dynamically change the background of an item in a listview in JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, javafx, colors

I am writing a program which places a set of items in a listview.
Then it checks if it finds the items in the database. If the item can't be found in the database I want to change the background of that item in my listview.
I am using JavaFX for this program.

How do i do this?

Comment: Please show some code - ideally a [MCVE] which includes the class definition for the items in your list and your cell factory (if any).

Comment: Please, paste the code you're describing, and tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom cell factory for the ListView that checks for the condition and applies the appropriate css style class to each item/cell.

The following code shows how to go about that for a Listview with items of type String.

```
     listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>(){

        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> p) {

            ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>(){

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String t, boolean bln) {
                    super.updateItem(t, bln);
                    if (t != null ) {
                        setText( t);

                        if (item_is_not_available){

                            if (!getStyleClass().contains("mystyleclass") {
                                getStyleClass().add("mystyleclass");
                            }

                        } else {
                            getStyleClass().remove("mystyleclass");
                        }
                    } else {
                        setText("");
                    }
                }

            };

            return cell;
        }
    });
```

In your css file, a possible definition of `mystyleclass` could look like this (displaying items that are not available with a red background):

```
.mystyleclass{
    -fx-background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: That's full of bugs. You must handle the case where the item is `null` in the `updateItem(...)` method. You must also remove the style class if the cell is updated from an item that is available to one that is not available, and you need to ensure you don't add `"mystyleclass"` multiple times to the same cell.

Comment: I edited the answer. As for "You must also remove the style class if the cell is updated from an item that is available to one that is not available", I assume the example shows enough to understand the concept hand handle the other cases appropriately.

Comment: But it doesn't actually work. With this implementation, if the user scrolls around, the wrong cells will have the given style class.

Comment: You are right on that. Added the missing part now, even tried to run it and it works.

Comment: Since OP wants to change the background, you may also complete the answer by adding a definition of "mystyleclass" on how it can be look like.

Comment: The logic's still not right. What if the cell was displaying one available item and then is reused to display another available item? You will remove the style class instead of keeping it. I would use a CSS Pseudoclass for this... though I'm not going to post an answer unless the OP actually clarifies what they want: there are too many unknowns in the question.

Comment: The code adds the style to cells that are not available and remove it for others. If the style gets removed from a cell that didn't have the syle, it does not result in an error (although it might not be nice).  HOWEVER, because of the way the question was asked, I initially just wanted to point out the idea of using a cell factory to OP and not write down his whole logic for him.

Comment: You flipped the logic, but it's still not quite correct. (Cell containing item not available, has "mystyleclass"; suppose now it gets reused to contain a different item that is not available - your if condition will be false (because `getStyleClass().contains("mystyleclass")` is true), so your `else` clause gets invoked and you incorrectly remove the style class. So in this circumstance your display would be incorrect.) Bottom line is that style classes are horrible to work with in cells, because they're implemented as a list (not a set).

Comment: My guess is that the OP actually wants a solution where the condition might change after the list view is displayed, btw, which is a whole other issue. But unless he actually clarifies what he wants there's really no way to know.

Comment: Fixed the logic for you ;)