# Dynamically change the background of a cell in a ListView

Tags: java, listview, javafx, background, cell

I have a problem with my listview.
I have some code that changes the background of some cells in a ListView. But when i scroll in that listview the background changes to the wrong cells.

Here you see some code:
Change the background of the cell in a listview:

```
@Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
            ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String t, boolean bln) {
                    super.updateItem(t, bln);
                    if (t != null) {
                        setText(t);

                        if (!controller.checkGerecht(t)) {

                           if (!getStyleClass().contains("mystyleclass")) {
                                getStyleClass().add("mystyleclass");
                                foutieveInput.add(t);
                            } else {      
                               getStyleClass().remove("mystyleclass");
                            }
                        } else {
                            setText(t);

                        }
                    }
                }
```

The css file:

```
.mystyleclass{
    -fx-background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the logic implemented incorrectly, assuming you want the red background only on cells for which `controller.checkGerecht(t)` is `false`. You're trying to remove the style class if it's not present: you want to remove the style class if your condition doesn't hold. (I.e. you have `remove` in the wrong `else` clause.)

Additionally, you need to handle the case where the cell is updated to hold a `null` value (e.g. if it is empty):

```
public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
    ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String t, boolean bln) {
            super.updateItem(t, bln);
            if (t == null) {
                setText(null);
                getStyleClass().remove("mystyleclass");
            } else {
                setText(t);

                if (!controller.checkGerecht(t)) {

                    if (!getStyleClass().contains("mystyleclass")) {
                        getStyleClass().add("mystyleclass");
                        foutieveInput.add(t);
                    } 
                } else {
                    getStyleClass().remove("mystyleclass");
                }
            }

        }
    };
    return cell ;
}
```

Comment: Actually, how is this different to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696033/how-do-i-dynamically-change-the-background-of-an-item-in-a-listview-in-javafx)?