# How would I go about styling cells in a ListView based on a condition in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I found this post and I think it's very similar but I need some help adapting it to my case: [How to set the style of list view cells based on a condition in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097025/how-to-set-the-style-of-list-view-cells-based-on-a-condition-in-javafx)

Basically, I have a ListView and I want to change the background color of individual cells based on a condition. I have an arrayList `locations` of `location` objects, and I want to check a property of a single location to determine the background color of the cell. the ListView is populated by iterating through `locations` and getting the name of each location, then storing it in arraylist, then finally populating the listView. Here is relevant code:

```
@FXML
private ListView<String> locationListView;
private ArrayList<String> locationList = new ArrayList();

private ListProperty<String> listProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>();

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {
            locationList.add(locations.get(i).name());
        }
    }

    locationListView.itemsProperty().bind(listProperty);
    listProperty.set(FXCollections.observableArrayList(locationList));
}
```

And here is where I am struggling, I copied/modified from the post I linked above.

```
locationListView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>() {
@Override
protected void updateItem(String c, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(c, empty);
    for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {
            if (locations.get(i).visited) { 
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
            } 
        }
    }
});
```

I'm aware this is long ways from working as intended but I'm not sure where to go from here, I think I'm approaching it incorrectly.

Overall I have maybe made this more complicated than it needs to be (new to javafx), but any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should probably use `ListView<Location>` then you can follow the example you linked to.

Comment: @Sedrick  I had a feeling I had to do that... cheers, thanks for the help!

Comment: Note: If you override `ListCell.updateItem` there always needs to be some part that changes the visuals back to the original state in case the cell becomes empty/the cell item is replaced with one not requiring this kind of markup. Also not sure why you keep `locationList` as a field: `observableArrayList` creates a copy of the data in a new list. Also not sure why you use a `ListProperty` instead of using the `item` property directly (`locationListView.setItems(FXCollections....);`)...